# Unable to bind to ngTable from dataset

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

So in Angular, I am trying to bind a ng-Table to a dataset but does not seem to work with my response data. I think my problem is somewhere in here,
""-- self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: 'data' }); --""
 but am not sure. Also, I am getting no errors console.
Can someone shed a little light, thanks.

**Controller:**

```
UtilityApp.controller('u_CompaniesController', function ($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

$scope.message = "Companies";
$scope.myData = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Utility/GetCompanies',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var self = this;
    var data = response.data;
    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: 'data' });

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("error");
});
```

});

**Ng-Table**

```
  <div ng-controller="u_CompaniesController">
    <table id="tblCompanies" ng-table="vm.tableParams"  class="table" show-filter="true">   
        <tr ng-repeat="c in $tableParams">
            <td title="'CompanyCd'" filter="{ CompanyCd: 'text'}" sortable="'CompanyCd'">
                {{c.CompanyCd}}
            </td>
            <td title="'CompanyName'" filter="{ CompanyName: 'text'}" sortable="'CompanyName'">
                {{c.CompanyName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `var self = this` to right under the controller declaration. You should also update your html by `ng-controller="u_CompaniesController as vm"`. Read [this blogpost](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) For more information on Controller as Syntax.

Or just use `$scope`, i'd recommend it if you're just getting started with angular. In this case remove the `vm` from your html `ng-table="tableParams"`

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: 'data' });
```

**Controller**

```
   UtilityApp.controller('u_CompaniesController', function ($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

$scope.message = "Companies";
$scope.myData = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Utility/GetCompanies',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    var data = response.data;
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: 'data' });

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("error");
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-controller="u_CompaniesController">
    <table id="tblCompanies" ng-table="tableParams"  class="table" show-filter="true">   
        <tr ng-repeat="c in $tableParams">
            <td title="'CompanyCd'" filter="{ CompanyCd: 'text'}" sortable="'CompanyCd'">
                {{c.CompanyCd}}
            </td>
            <td title="'CompanyName'" filter="{ CompanyName: 'text'}" sortable="'CompanyName'">
                {{c.CompanyName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that almost worked, it shows the rows, but they are all empty.

Comment: Since you're getting the data from the server, try this http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/VLqqjP?editors=101